# How exactly is the Twilio Lookup API v2 discerning its valid property?

Tags: validation, twilio, phone-number

Looking at [these docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api#phone-number-lookup), I see a `valid` property in the return. I've been struggling to find answers on what exactly this means. The docs say

> Boolean which indicates if the phone number is in a valid range that **can be freely assigned by a carrier to a user**.

Likely helpful context: we're looking to enhance our validation by:

1. Ensuring a phone number is actually registered to a human and active.
2. Ensuring the area code and first 3 digits are actually possible combinations.
3. Ensuring duplications/known fakes aren't passed in. Ex: 555-5555

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `valid` property satisfies your 2nd and 3rd needs. A valid phone number is one that a carrier could assign to a user, but doesn't necessarily have to be assigned. This does mean that the area code and following number are possible, and that fake numbers are not possible.

To verify the number is real and belongs to a user, the best thing to do is to [verify by sending it a message or calling it and verifying a given code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api).